# Does Cryptsy reuses market IDs?

Tags: exchanges, api, cryptsy, bittrex, mintpal

Cryptsy has a lot of markets. Each market has its own ID. Now markets have an ID in the range [1,220]. Sometimes old markets are deleted. Are the IDs of that markets reused or not?

I have the same question for Bittrex and MintPal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't reuse market IDs. For example, SaturnCoin (SAT) has been deleted and replaced with SAT2. That was market ID [168](http://saturncointalk.org/index.php?topic=26.0)(search for cryptsy. It links to https://www.cryptsy.com/markets/view/168). If you want to go there, you'll be redirected to the home page. SAT2 has market ID 233. Why wouldn't they replace SAT/BCT with SAT2/BTC? Anyhow, market 248 (latest at the moment) does also exist, which is later introduced then SAT2 and probably also later then the removal of SAT. Based on this, I think I can safely say they will not reuse the market IDs. And why would they? It will only be confusing and frustrating.

For the other two exchanges, I am 100% sure they will not reuse their IDs. If you go to a specific markets, the url consists of something like `BC/BTC`. Unless their is some new coin stupid enough to launch with the same abbreviation , there is no chance it will have the same ID.